# Java, let CookieHandler work on only one instance

Tags: java, cookies, setcookie

I don't know how CookieHandler works system wide, I did view the source of CookieHandler but found no more information except the get/set methods. Where do TCP/HTTP connections use instance of CookieHandler, which I set by

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(...)
```

Which source file I should refer to? `URLConnection` & `HttpURLConnection` don't seem have things to do with it.

Help, thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
Is it possible to apply CookieHandler to only one instance in which `setDefault` is invoked.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. This [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/cookiehandler.html) might hopefully have some info, namely "That is, URLs that use HTTP as the protocol, `new URL("http://example.com")` for example, will use the HTTP protocol handler. This protocol handler calls back to the CookieHander object, if set, to handle the state management."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using this

```
private static class DelegatingCookieManager extends CookieManager {
    @Override public void setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy cookiePolicy) {
        delegate.get().setCookiePolicy(cookiePolicy);
    }

    @Override public CookieStore getCookieStore() {
        return delegate.get().getCookieStore();
    }

    @Override public Map<String, List<String>> get(
            URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        return delegate.get().get(uri, requestHeaders);
    }

    @Override public void put(URI uri, Map<String,
            List<String>> responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        delegate.get().put(uri, responseHeaders);
    }
}
```

which gets installed globally

```
static {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new DelegatingCookieManager());
}
```

but has no state and delegate to a

```
private static final ThreadLocal<CookieManager> delegate =
     new ThreadLocal<CookieManager>();
```

which gets instantiated in the class where it gets used

```
private final CookieManager ownCookieManager = new CookieManager();
```

like

```
delegate.set(ownCookieManager);
doRequest();
```

Comment: I turned to HttpClient, the `setCookieStore` method.

Comment: @user435657 That's probably the way to go. It's that a few of megabytes code feels like too much for parsing and writing a single line (`Cookie`/`Set-Cookie`).

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc for `java.net.CookieManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) gives a pretty good overview of how CookieHandler fits in.