# Puzzled by CookieHandler

Tags: java, http, cookies

I need to access some web pages and pass cookies around the way browsers do. This is easily done using

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new MyCookieManager());
```

but this introduces global state which I need to avoid (Imagine accessing two accounts on the same server concurrently). So what I'd like to do is something like

```
String doGetWithCookies(URL url, MyCookies myCookies) {
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    myCookies.addToRequest(...);
    myCookies.updateFromResponse(...);
    return getHttpBody(conn);
}
```

but I can't see how to do it. The methods `CookieManager.get` and `put` do accept an `URL`, but I want to use

- the same cookies with different `URL`s
- different cookies for the same `URL` for different accounts

What I've tried: Nothing as there are just four methods available and a single subclass and nothing fits. Parsing the headers manually is surely doable but IMHO no option in 2014. I know about the [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x), but 1. I'd hope something that trivial needs no half a megabyte library, 2. at the first glance I can't see a solution there either.

#### Clarification:

Imagine you want to lock to SO as two different users. You can do it by using two computers or two different browsers (Chrome and Firefox) on a single computer. You can't do it in two tabs of a single browser.

What I want is equivalent to the possibility of simulating two browser. In the meantime I've found a related question and posted [hacky solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672958/581205) to it.

Still I'm looking for an explanation behind the `CookieHandler` design.

Comment: Can you better explain your needs? Do you want many users to be connected in the same session at the same time? what do you mean by "different cookies for the same URL for different accounts". It is always the case, from the moment you have different sessions (internally a cookie is used to differentiate each session)

Comment: @ZiedHamdi: "internally a cookie is used to differentiate each session:" - yes, but only if you have different cookies. Open two different browser and login to SO with two different accounts. It works. Try the same in two tabs of a single browser. It doesn't work (as the cookies are shared). I'd like to be able to simulate multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending your requests to the server?

If you're using HttpUrlConnection, then you could implement your own cookies. Every time you make a request, add your `Cookie:foo=1;bar=2` header to the request. Every time you read a response, check for a `Cookie` header and store it for subsequent requests.

One tricky part will be knowing when to send a cookie, based on the URL being requested.

There's nothing built-in to the JDK to do this besides CookieHandler, which is lacking.

HttpClient might be a good option, as it has support for [granular cookies](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html).

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to hack the request reader so it won't use the standard "sessionId" parameter but your own "tabSessionId". This should be done by overriding the header parsing method. 
Try overriding java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderField(int) to use your own cookie when "sessionId" is requested

Answer (score 0):

I actually like your ["hacky" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672958/581205) if you are working with multiple threads and you can guarantee that the same thread is responsible for accessing resources on behalf of the same user. If that is not the case, i.e. two or more threads need to share a user account and the corresponding cookies or a single thread needs to access resources for multiple users, this solution will probably not work...

My first attempt would have been to set an individual `CookieManager` for every user account:

```
String doGetForUser(URL url, String username) {
    synchronized (...) {
        CookieManager.setDefault(getCookieManagerForUser(username));
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Calling getInputStream on the connection automatically retrieves
        // cookies from the CookieManager and stores new cookies that have been
        // sent from the server.
        return getHttpBody(conn);
    }
}
```

This is pretty similar to [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23672958/581205) except that it does not rely on the one-user-per-thread assumption. However, locking the `CookieManager` the entire time isn't probably what you want. But as it turns out, the `HttpURLConnection` saves a reference to the default `CookieManager` in its [constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?av=f#814). Exploiting this, we get what I would really call a hacky solution:

```
String doGetForUser(URL url, String username) {
    HttpsUrlConnection conn;
    synchronized (...) {
        CookieManager.setDefault(getCookieManagerForUser(username));
        // this saves the current CookieManager
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        CookieManager.setDefault( ... ); // restore original one?
    }
    return getHttpBody(conn);
}
```

Now we "only" lock the `CookieManager` for the connection setup which will probably increase concurrency. But it's still pretty ugly and you would now have to make sure that you lock the `CookieManager` if you make requests from somewhere else that should not use user-specific cookies...

I skimmed the source code of `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpClient` to see when it actually retrieves and stores cookies. Apparently, the only place where the `CookieManager` is queried for the cookies that should be sent is in the private [`setCookieHeader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java?av=f#1371) method, which is called by both `getOutputStream` and `getInputStream` before the request is sent. `setCookieHeader` passes the current request headers to the installed `CookieManager`. Maybe we could use these headers instead?

```
String doGetForUser(URL url, String username) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Username", username);
    return getHttpBody(conn);
}

class UsernameCookieHandler extends CookieHandler {
    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>>get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) throws IOException {
        if (requestHeaders.containsKey("X-Username"))
            return getUserSpecificCookies(uri, requestHeaders);
        else
            return getCommonCookies(uri, requestHeaders);
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getUserSpecificCookies(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) {
        // evaluate X-Username and get cookies from a special CookieStore or so...
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getCommonCookies(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) {
        // get cookies from a common CookieStore...
    }

    @Override
    public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException {
        // ???
    }
}
```

This one retrieves user-specific cookies if there is an application-defined request header `X-Username` and gets a common set of cookies if no such header exists. However, updating the user-specific cookies won't be this easy because the server will most certainly not send the `X-Username` header back to us. The idea would of course be to somehow determine the username from the `responseHeaders`. But I currently don't see a way how to inject the correct header field in the server`s response without setting up a proxy server.... Sorry :(

---

FYI: The only place I could find that calls `CookieManager.put` is the private [`parseHTTPHeader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/net/www/http/HttpClient.java?av=f#725) method in `HttpClient`. This method is of course invoked from `getInputStream` before you can read the response body.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here, as you mentioned is that

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new MyCookieManager());
```

introduces a global state. Why Oracle failed to provide a simple means of managing cookies on a per session basis is beyond me.

Here's how you can do it, though.

1. Include a `URLConnectionCookieManager` class with two methods: `setCookiesFromCookieJar(urlConnection)` and `putCookiesInCookieJar(urlConnection)`.
2. For each separate session, create an instance of the `URLConnectionCookieManager` class. (Note that its methods are NOT static; they are instance methods.)
3. Before sending a request, call `urlConnectionCookieManager.setCookiesFromCookieJar(urlConnection)`. This method retrieves cookies from the "cookie jar" and adds them to the connection's request headers.
4. After sending a request, call `urlConnectionCookieManager.putCookiesInCookieJar(urlConnection)`. This method retrieves cookies from the connection and puts them in the "cookie jar".

Make sure you use the instance of `URLConnectionCookieManager` that corresponds to the "session".

The URLConnectionCookieManager class looks like this:

```
package http;

import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class URLConnectionCookieManager implements Serializable
  {

  public URLConnectionCookieManager()
    {
    this(null, null);
    }

  public URLConnectionCookieManager(
    CookieHandler cookieHandler)
    {
    setCookieHandler(cookieHandler);
    }

  public URLConnectionCookieManager(
    CookieStore cookieStore,
    CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
    {
    CookieHandler cookieHandler = createCookieHandler(cookieStore, cookiePolicy);
    setCookieHandler(cookieHandler);
    }

  public void putCookiesInCookieJar(
    URLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException
    {
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
    URL url = urlConnection.getURL();

    URI uri = null;
    try
      {
      uri = url.toURI();
      }
    catch (URISyntaxException urise)
      {
      System.out.println("Unable to convert URL to URI while putting cookies in cookie jar.");
      throw new IOException(urise);
      }

    CookieHandler cookieHandler = getCookieHandler();
    cookieHandler.put(uri, headers);
    }

  public void setCookiesFromCookieJar(
    URLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException
    {
    Map<String, List<String>> headerMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    URL url = urlConnection.getURL();

    URI uri = null;
    try
      {
      uri = url.toURI();
      }
    catch (URISyntaxException urise)
      {
      System.out.println("Unable to convert URL to URI while setting cookies from cookie jar.");
      throw new IOException(urise);
      }

    CookieHandler cookieHandler = getCookieHandler();
    headerMap = cookieHandler.get(uri, headerMap);

    Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> headerSet = headerMap.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> headerIterator = headerSet.iterator();
    boolean hasNextPair = headerIterator.hasNext();
    while (hasNextPair)
      {
      Map.Entry<String, List<String>> pair = headerIterator.next();
      String key = pair.getKey();
      List<String> cookieList = pair.getValue();

      Iterator<String> cookieIterator = cookieList.iterator();
      boolean hasNextCookie = cookieIterator.hasNext();
      while (hasNextCookie)
        {
        String cookie = cookieIterator.next();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty(key, cookie);
        hasNextCookie = cookieIterator.hasNext();
        }

      hasNextPair = headerIterator.hasNext();
      }
    }

  public CookieHandler getCookieHandler()
    {
    return this.cookieHandler_;
    }

  protected CookieHandler createCookieHandler(
    CookieStore cookieStore,
    CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
    {
    CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager(cookieStore, cookiePolicy);

    return cookieHandler;
    }

  protected void setCookieHandler(
    CookieHandler cookieHandler)
    {
    this.cookieHandler_ = cookieHandler;
    }

  private CookieHandler cookieHandler_;

  }
```